# Как использовать Анимацию в Android без остановки?

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация, android-animation

Как использовать Анимацию в Android без остановки?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360">

</rotate>
```

Вся проблема в том что анимация происходит как то не так. Тобишь она воспроизводится. Под конец останавливается на 500мс. А после опять воспроизвордиться. А можно ли как то зациклить это чтобы она вообще не останаваливалась. Тобишь было ЕДИНЫМ Целым

Comment: Добавьте и код из активити

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описанное, вроде, похоже на действие дефолтного интерполятора, который определяет как анимация должна проигрываться с течением времени. По дефолту она проигрывается с ускорением в начале и замедлением в конце. Чтобы скорость не менялась надо использовать линейный интерполятор:

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```

Полезная инфа: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/interpolator.php

Comment: android:interpolator="linear_interpolator"

Нет такого в  Android

Comment: Я добавил программно его и заработало все. Но все же почему через XML не работает?

Comment: @xTIGRx, исправил в ответе

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="repeat">

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю что этот атрибут дает вам лаг

```
android:repeatMode="restart"
```